# Strange speed changes in Haskell profiling

Tags: haskell, optimization, profiling, ghc

I'm profiling Haskell program by compiling it with `ghc -prof -auto-all -O solve_sudoku.hs`, and running with `solve_sudoku.exe params +RTS -p` which gives me a log.

I've got a function that is supposed to be called a lot, but it does not appear in log. The question is different though. Here is part of the code:

```
-- Cell of a puzzle
data Cell a = Cell {values :: [a], column :: Int, row :: Int}

updateCell :: [Cell Int] -> Cell Int -> Cell Int
updateCell list cell@(Cell v x y) = Cell v' x y
        where v' = if length v < 2 then filter (not . same) v
                                   else filter correct v
              correct c     = all (good c) [row, column, part]
              same c        = c `elem` (concat . concatMap chosen
                                 $ [row, column, part])
              good a thing  = allright required vars
                          where vars = [a] : callBy thing
              chosen thing  = filter ((==1) . length) $ callBy thing
              necessary f   = map values $ filter (id f) list          -- this is where problem is
              unique        = id
              sameBy f      = ( == f cell) . f
              callBy f      = necessary $ sameBy f
              required      = [1..9]
```

if I run test with this code, I get following log: http://pastebin.com/cxnwLkSM
but if I replace `filter (id f) list` with `filter (unique f) list`, I get following: http://pastebin.com/nUNBAEp4

The question is: why does the execution take twice as long if `id` is called through another function name? I guess that it has something to do with remembering evaluated values during lazy evaluation, but I don't really get it.

If I remove both `unique` and `id`, execution is slightly slower than with `unique f`.

I'm running Windows 7 x64, Glassgow Haskell Compiler installed with Haskell Platform. Here is output of `ghc -v`:

```
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.6.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.4.1
Using binary package database: C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\lib\package.conf.d\package.cache
Using binary package database: C:\Users\idji\AppData\Roaming\ghc\i386-mingw32-7.6.3\package.conf.d\package.cache
hiding package Cabal-1.16.0 to avoid conflict with later version Cabal-1.18.1.2
hiding package binary-0.5.1.1 to avoid conflict with later version binary-0.7.1.0
hiding package containers-0.4.2.1 to avoid conflict with later version containers-0.5.0.0
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.3.0.0-9d603ae4e062e1401099a3daa8931d0f
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-0.5.0.0-4093e6ff1e8ebdba04ec892df9ac108f
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.6.0.1-f0c2cc6dcf0e12bf75312a2e7f354095
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.8.0.0-42f1e6e55511ef4dff7e4249580faf8f
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
Hsc static flags: -static
```

Comment: What if you put an `{-# INLINE unique #-}` and a type signature on it?

Comment: I would guess something to do with polymorphism of `id` and you not using optimizations.  Please don't assume profiled (`-prof`) or non-`-O2` compiled code represent anything meaningful wrt performance.

Comment: @bheklilr I changed lines to `necessary f   = map values $ filter (unique f) list
              {-# INLINE unique #-}
              unique        :: (Cell Int -> Bool) -> (Cell Int -> Bool)` and got same speed as using `unique` without inlining. `unique` was _faster_ than `id`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson do you mean that I should use `-O2` instead of `-O` when compiling, and should compare real execution times when without `-prof`, not just use profiler logs?

Comment: `-prof` inserts all sorts of code and prevents significant amounts of inlining, which in turn prevents other optimizations.  In short: profiling is actually much less useful than many people think because of how it changes the very properties you usually are wanting to measure.

Comment: "At present, -O2 is nearly indistinguishable from -O." - Section 6.2 of http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/index.html

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson when I try to recompile, having `-O` changed to `-O2`, ghc does nothing new (like flags did not changed)

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I compiled and checked without `-prof` -- it takes about thrice less time than I measured. Now there is no dramatic difference in performance.